# Count number of patterns with a single command

Tags: string, bash, count

I'd like to count the number of occurrences in a string. For example, in this string :

```
'apache2|ntpd'
```

there are 2 different strings separated by `|` character.
 Another example :

```
'apache2|ntpd|authd|freeradius'
```

In this case there are 4 different strings separated by `|` character.

Would you know a shell or perl command that could simply count this for me?

Comment: You need to count the number of occurences of the pipe symbol, then add one.

Comment: IN="bla@some.com;john@home.com"

mails=$(echo $IN | tr ";" "\n")

for addr in $mails
do
    echo "> [$addr]"
done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use awk command as below;

```
echo "apache2|ntpd" | awk -F'|' '{print NF}'
```

-F'|'  is to field separator;
NF means Number of Fields

Example;

```
user@host:/tmp$ echo 'apache2|ntpd|authd|freeradius' | awk -F'|' '{print NF}'
4
```

you can also use this;

```
user@host:/tmp$ echo "apache2|ntpd" | tr '|' ' ' | wc -w
2
user@host:/tmp$ echo 'apache2|ntpd|authd|freeradius' | tr '|' ' ' | wc -w
4


tr '|' ' ' : translate | to space
wc -w : print the word counts
```

if there are spaces in the string, wc -w not correct result, so

```
echo 'apac he2|ntpd' | tr '|' '\n' | wc -l



user@host:/tmp$ echo 'apac he2|ntpd' | tr '|' ' ' | wc -w
3   --> not correct
user@host:/tmp$ echo 'apac he2|ntpd' | tr '|' '\n' | wc -l
2

 tr '|' '\n' : translate | to newline
 wc -l : number of lines
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this solution solved my request !

Comment: your `tr | wc` method fails if there are spaces in the string.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : Thanks, you are right, I updated ans.

Answer (score 1):

Do can do this just within `bash` without calling external languages like `awk` or external programs like `grep` and `tr`.

```
data='apache2|ntpd|authd|freeradius'
res=${data//[!|]/}
num_strings=$(( ${#res} + 1 ))
echo $num_strings
```

Let me explain.

`res=${data//[!|]/}` removes all characters that are **not** (that's the `!`) pipes (`|`).

`${#res}` gives the length of the resulting string.

`num_strings=$(( ${#res} + 1 ))`  adds one to the number of pipes to get the number of fields.

It's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Another pure `bash` technique using positional-parameters

```
$ userString="apache2|ntpd|authd|freeradius"
$ printf "%s\n" $(IFS=\|; set -- $userString; printf "%s\n" "$#")
4
```

Thanks to [cdarke's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736308/cdarke) suggestion from the commands, the above command can directly store the count to a variable

```
$ printf -v count "%d" $(IFS=\|; set -- $userString; printf "%s\n" "$#")
$ printf "%d\n" "$count"
4
```

Comment: It might be worth adding that the number can be put into a variable using `-v var` to the left-most `printf` (in which case you probably want to change the formatting to `"%d"`, i.e. no new-line).

Comment: It could also be simplified to `count=$( IFS=\|; set -- $userString; echo "$#" )`

Comment: You're doing it inefficiently: the first form doesn't need an extra `printf` and process substitution: `(IFS=\|; set -- $userString; printf '%s\n' "$#")` is enough; in the second form, it's enough to just do `count=$(IFS=\|; set -- $userString; printf "%s\n" "$#")`. Now, the method itself is broken as it will fail if the string contains matching globs (though, you could use `set -f`, to turn off globbing, but I wouldn't recommend it). (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) To get rid of the horrible antipattern you're using, consider using `read` to split your string and count the number of fields: `IFS=\| read -ra array <<< "$userString"; echo "${#array[@]}"` (works safely, and is semantically correct if `userString` doesn't contain newlines), or `IFS=\| read -r -d '' -a array < <(printf '%s\0' "$userString"); echo "${#array[@]}"` for the bullet proof way of splitting a string. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) Alternatively, you could realize that you only need the number of `|` characters, plus one. Then: `count=${userString//[^|]}; count=$(({#count}+1))` will do the job as well.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: thanks for some excellent suggestions. Initial idea was to use `read`, but haven't posted any stuff here with positional parameter expansion, so decided to have a go at it. Much appreciate your time

Comment: Thank you guys these solutions helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

With `wc` and parameter expansion:

```
$ data='apache2|ntpd|authd|freeradius'
$ wc -w <<< ${data//|/ }
4
```

Using parameter expansion, all pipes are replaced with spaces. The result string is passed to `wc -w` for word count.

As @gniourf_gniourf mentionned, it works with what at first looks like process names but will fail if strings contain spaces.

Comment: This obviously fails if the string contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `grep` as well-

```
echo "apache2|ntpd|authd|freeradius" | grep -o "|" | wc -l
Output-
3
```

That output is the number of pipes.

To get the number of commands-

```
var=$(echo "apache2|ntpd|authd|freeradius" | grep -o "|" | wc -l)
echo $((var + 1))
Output - 
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use awk to count the occurrances of delimiters +1:

```
$ awk '{print gsub(/\|/,"")+1}'  <(echo "apache2|ntpd|authd|freeradius")
4
```

Answer (score -1):

may be this will help you.

```
IN="apache2|ntpd"

mails=$(echo $IN | tr "|" "\n")

for addr in $mails
do
    echo "> [$addr]"
done
```

Comment: Please either format the code correctly or add some semi-colons. This code gives a syntax error as it stands, and even when those are corrected does not give the number of fields.